# Creating New Row in Pandas based off Condition and Max values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, apply

I have a pandas df that contains the following data:

```
Index  Race_id     Place_payout      Place_outcome
5      7019        7659.0              1
6      7019       11096.0              1
7      7019       14791.0              0
9      7019        5810.0              0
10     7019        3093.0              0
11     7019       25335.0              0
12     7019       11516.0              0
13     7019        4571.0              0
14     7019        3798.0              0
```

I need to create one new column.

This column is the dividend for that horse and is based on the following formula:

place_div = ((((0.78* Total_Amount_Wagered_For_Race)-(Maximum_Amount_Wagered + Current_Row_Value_Wagered))/current_row_value_wagered)/2)+1

Unless the current row is the max within the group then I need to use the second highest value as the maximum amount wagered

This column would look as follows:

```
Index  Race_id     Place_payout      Place_outcome   place_div
5      7019        7659.0              1               7.618085
6      7019       11096.0              1               5.723
7      7019       14791.0              0               4.668035
9      7019        5810.0              0               9.565131
10     7019        3093.0              0               16.64983
11     7019       25335.0              0               3.349552
12     7019       11516.0              0               5.568983
13     7019        4571.0              0               11.75124
14     7019        3798.0              0               13.83765
```

I tried using the following code:

```
proba_win['div_place'] = proba_win['place_payout'].loc[proba_win.groupby('race_id')['place_payout'].idxmax()]
```

In the hopes this would extract the value within the group for the maximum payout, but the resulting df is then:

```
Index     div_place
5         NaN
6         NaN
7         NaN
9         NaN
10        NaN
11    25335.0
12        NaN
13        NaN
```

Moreover, I can't seem to find a way to locate the second highest value.
Using nlargest returns an error:

```
 proba_win['div_place'] = proba_win.groupby('race_id')['place_payout'].nlargest(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1551-47283ddea8e5>", line 1, in <module>
    proba_win['div_place'] = proba_win.groupby('race_id')['place_payout'].nlargest(1)

  File "C:\Users\fredd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3163, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)

  File "C:\Users\fredd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3239, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)

  File "C:\Users\fredd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3873, in _sanitize_column
    value = reindexer(value)

  File "C:\Users\fredd\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3869, in reindexer
    ) from err

TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

I'm assuming the solution would use some kind of apply with a built helper function, but I haven't been able to develop a solution yet.

Comment: So the total amount wagered would be the sum of the 'Place_payout' for the group, and the max wager would be the max of said column? or is there another wager column that I am not seeing?

Comment: Yes, the total amount wagered would be the sum of Place_payout, and max_amount_wagered is the max of the Place_payout column within the race_id group, and current_row_value_wagered is the value of that cell within the Place_payout column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this but this is the simplest. I'm defining the function outside of the apply operation for readability's sake.

```
def get_place_div(row):
    total_wagered, max_wagered = df.loc[df.Race_id==row.Race_id,'Place_payout'].agg(['sum','max'])
    place_div = ((((0.78*total_wagered)-max_wagered+row.Place_payout)/row.Place_payout)/2)+1
    return place_div

df['place_div']=df.apply(lambda row: get_div_place(row),axis=1)
```

Comment: when attempting to run this code, I get an error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: I edited the comment, I forgot the 'Place_payout' index in the .iloc. Should work now

Comment: Could you explain a bit how this is actually functioning? I understand the apply and lambda, but the df.Race_id == row.race_id? isn't that just finding the location in the df where the race id matches the row race id and returning the value in the place_payout column?

Comment: @Redratz, The df.loc[df.Race_id==row.Race_id,'Place_payout'] will return all rows in the 'Place_payout' column in where the Race_id == rows race_id. Then by calling the .agg(['sum','max']) function, it is returning the respective sum and max for the aforementioned subgroup

Comment: do you know how to expand this function to use the sum of the two largest values instead of just the max value?

Comment: You would call "sort values" and select the first two items